# error in computing eigen values

Tags: c++, eigenvalue, opencv3.2

I am trying to find eigen values for a syymetric matrix as follows:-

```
    Mat t(2, 2, CV_32F); 
    t.at<float>(0, 0) = 1;
    t.at<float>(0, 1) = 0;
    t.at<float>(1, 0) = 0;
    t.at<float>(1, 1) = 128;

    Mat eigVal,eigVec;
    eigen(t,eigVal,eigVec);
```

When I am printing the eigen values for this matrix it gives me correct answer.

```
cout << eigVal.at<float>(0) << "," << eigVal.at<float>(1) << "\n";
```

The output which I get is 128,1. But when I am changing my matrix as follows:-

```
t.at<float>(0, 0) = 4;
t.at<float>(0, 1) = 2;
t.at<float>(1, 0) = 1;
t.at<float>(1, 1) = 3;
```

I am not getting correct response. The output which I am expecting is 5,2. But instead I am getting output as 5.56155 and 1.43845. 
Can anyone tell me where I did mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eigen` only works on symmetric matrices (those with equal values of either side of the main diagonal). You need `eigenNonSymmetric` for non-symmetric matrices:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Mat t(2, 2, CV_32F);
  t.at<float>(0, 0) = 4;
  t.at<float>(0, 1) = 2;
  t.at<float>(1, 0) = 1;
  t.at<float>(1, 1) = 3;

  Mat eigVal,eigVec;
  eigenNonSymmetric(t,eigVal,eigVec);

  cout << eigVal.at<float>(0) << "," << eigVal.at<float>(1) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5,2
```